# MongoDB Atlas search filter range with an OR criteria

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas

I would like to do a range search on a date using MongoDB Atlas Search, but I also need to include search results where there is no date at all. This is how I would do this in a `$match` stage of an aggregation pipeline:

```
$match: {
    $or: [
        {
            publish_start_date: {
                $lte: todayDateTime,
            },
        },
        {
            publish_start_date: undefined,
        },
    ],
}
```

Here is the equivalent of the first part in an atlas `$search`

```
$search: {
    index: "iapp-component-search",
    compound: {
        filter: [
            {
                range: {
                    path: "publish_start_date",
                    lte: todayDateTime,
                },
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

I know I can simply add the `$match` stage to the aggregation pipeline after the `$search`, but the Atlas docs say this is not good for performance, so I would like to include it in the filter of the `$search`.

How would I add an "OR" clause to also include documents with a `publish_start_date` of `undefined` in the `$search` stage?

Comment: Index traversal requires there is one condition. Querying on two conditions is not satisfiable by a single index traversal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all documents that don't have a start date, write a placeholder value into the date e.g. 0000-00-00. If the missing date means something for your application, duplicate the data + placeholder into a new field.

Comment: I think you are right. I will default all dates to have a value rather than be undefined, then I no longer have the issue.